# How to disable auto genrated css in media folder at runtime Magento?

Tags: css, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7version. In this, My site is generating CSS file at run time in media folder(magento\media\css) 00f3d3f415b9352527c240b764ff14c3.css

it is not taking my orignal CSS from (magento/skin/frontend/default/ultimento/css) styles.css

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: remove JS/CSS cache from Cache Management

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer`, click on `CSS Settings` and set `Merge CSS Files` to `No`.  Clear your cache and you'll see the expected CSS again.

Comment: thanks it works and in my case there are two css(styles.css and scree.css) merged together.I just removed screen.css Then it is working fine.